# Jhipster microservices: JWT authentication: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, jwt, jhipster, jhipster-gateway

When I tried to visit a protected URL of microservice through the gateway eg: `HTTP://localhost:8080/services/microservicename/api/**` I am getting the  following error

`401 Unauthorized, full authentication requested` .

I am using JWT authentication for microservices and I do have a separate registry service. What might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The first step in debugging should be to see if you are getting authenticated with the gateway.

To get authenticated with the gateway pass in request body raw json data 
`{"username":"admin","password":"admin","rememberMe":"true"}`

 to the gateway authentication URL `http://localhost:8080/api/authenticate` and you will get an `id_token` in response. Use this id_token data as `Authorization Bearer` token in every request you would like to process which is protected eg:- `http://localhost:8080/services/microservicename/path`

Upon gateway authentication confirmation the second step to debug would be to see SecurityConfiguration.java in the config folder of a particular microservice you are trying to access. In the `SecurityFilterChain` function you would see something like `.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()`. The end of the antMatcher would be either `permitAll()` `authenticated()` or `hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)`.

1. If it is `permitAll()` all requests would reach microservice and get processed upon gateway authentication.
2. if it is `hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.Admin)` implies you would have to log in as that particular user. By default there are two users in Jhipster 'admin' {username:admin, password:admin} or user {username:user, password:user} and only then microservice controller will process your request.
3. if it `authenticated()` then any user type login would process the request.

If you are still facing the `401 Unauthorized, full authentication requested` it's probably the JWT secret that is causing the issue.
When I was debugging the problem, I initially missed the details on the original documentation page. https://www.jhipster.tech/security/

**Make sure you have the same jwt secret in `application-dev.yml` and `application-prod.yml` as the Gateway's application-dev.yml and application-prod.yml files.**